# Apache multihost does not respect server name

Tags: apache

I have two django applications on one machine. I would like to run them on the same address and port. So the user should be point to the correct address according the request domain/host. My current apache.conf file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 35.232.14.xxx
    ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.my_testing_domain.com
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that there is real IP address and real domain and other stuff required by Django app. I build the file according to the documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html#page-header (apache multiple sites on one IP) and https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-apache-and-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-14-04 (django with apache).

The thing is, that every request goes to the first VirtualHost (in this case the IP address). If I switch their order in the apache.conf, then every request goes to the domain VirtualHost.

So one of the sites is working correctly (always the first one).

Why the apache does not respect the server names? What am I missing?

Comment: You should not use an IP address for ``ServerName``. That is used in *name* based virtual hosting and dependent on using a name, not an IP in the URL. Any access to the server which can't be matched against ``ServerName by name, will be handled by the first ``VirtualHost``. For some related discussion read http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2012/10/requests-running-in-wrong-django.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add Server alias withou "www":

```
ServerAlias my_testing_domain.com
```

to the "domain based" virtual host. Now it works.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary if your application is really hosted at `www.my_testing_domain.com`. There's nothing magic about the `www.` prefix, it's exactly like any other name (except that customers love to have it added to their URLs). I suspect your Django app is redirecting from one address to the other.

Comment: It is necessary if the naked domain, rather than ``www`` was used when accessing the server. Apache can only match against what is defined by ``ServerName`` and ``ServerAlias``. Anything else hits the first ``VirtualHost``.